# Portability of em dash in html?

Tags: html, css

Is `<span>&#8212;</span>` portable across browsers (incl. desktop vs mobile) to represent em dashes? The last thing I want is for some people to see broken html on my pages. Is there a standard html or css solution?

Source for the above: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/em-dash/

Comment: What's wrong with just writing —?

Comment: @cSharp Those are equivalent

Comment: All browsers will interpret your code correctly. Whether or not an mdash will be correctly shown to the user is a matter of font, not browser — though you could be asking which browsers' default fonts support it. I haven't heard of such a font that does not — the mdash is a pretty standard character — though I may be wrong. You could use one of the cross-browser testing facilities; I do not know if there is a free one, but most offer some kind of free trial.

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: My fonts are either Courier New or Georgia; I suspect the fixed width nature of CN may prohibit it. But seeing as my page will only use CN for headers and such, hopefully it will not make a difference?